# CountryCodePicker Full Number Support to EditText

Tags: android

I'm trying to use country code using CountryCodePicker library 
https://github.com/hbb20/CountryCodePickerProject

And when i choose country from the list, i want that country code to display in EditText.
I dont know in which method to pass it.
Simple question, don't be angry :)

```
else {
    String code = ccp.getSelectedCountryCodeWithPlus();
    String number = edtPhone.getText().toString().trim();
    String phoneNumber = "+"+ code + number;

    Intent verify = new Intent (getActivity(), Verify.class);
    verify.putExtra("phonenumber", phoneNumber);
    verify.putExtra("phone", edtPhone.getText().toString());
    verify.putExtra("name",edtName.getText().toString());
    verify.putExtra("password",edtPassword.getText().toString());
    verify.putExtra("edtSecureCode",edtSecureCode.getText().toString());
    startActivity(verify);
}
```

It should pass EditText number to a second activity (full number included with country code, this is for firebase phone authentication, so it needs to know right number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to set country code to your edittext; try to set yourEditText like in your code;

```
else {
    String code = ccp.getSelectedCountryCodeWithPlus();

    => yourEditText.setText(""+code);                                

    String number = edtPhone.getText().toString().trim();

    String phoneNumber = "+"+ code + number;


    Intent verify = new Intent (getActivity(), Verify.class);
    verify.putExtra("phonenumber", phoneNumber);
    verify.putExtra("phone", edtPhone.getText().toString());
    verify.putExtra("name",edtName.getText().toString());
    verify.putExtra("password",edtPassword.getText().toString());
    verify.putExtra("edtSecureCode",edtSecureCode.getText().toString());
    startActivity(verify);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String code = codepicker.getSelectedCountryCodeWithPlus();
// Although it is written with plus but it has only the country code except the plus.
// So, we need to add the "+" manually

    editText.setText(""+code);   // displays the code in the edit text                              

    String number = phoneNo.getText().toString().trim();  //phoneNo that the user entered 
    String phoneNumber = "+" + code + number;   // complete phone number
 

    Intent verify = new Intent (getActivity(), Verify.class);
    verify.putExtra("phonenumber", phoneNumber);
    verify.putExtra("phone", edtPhone.getText().toString());
    verify.putExtra("name",edtName.getText().toString());
    verify.putExtra("password",edtPassword.getText().toString());
    verify.putExtra("edtSecureCode",edtSecureCode.getText().toString());
    startActivity(verify);
    finish();
}
```